# FollowHyperlink to open winform

Tags: vb.net

I have a Hyperlink in cell J24 of my spreadsheet. I want to open a winform when the user clicks on the hyperlink. In my old days of VBA that was pretty simple:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)


If Target.Parent.Address = "$L$48" Then

      frm.Show

End if
```

However, I have now transitioned to VB.net. I see that I have the followHyperlink event, but when I tried the following it did not work:

```
   Private Sub dsbEmployeeBoard_FollowHyperlink(Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink) Handles Me.FollowHyperlink

    Dim test As New frmCustomRanges

    If Target.Parent.Address = "$L$48" Then

        test.Show()


    End If


End Sub
```

Is there anyone who knows how to accomplish this in VB.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wire up the sub routine with the event:

```
Addhandler worksheet.FollowHyperLink, AddressOf FollowHyperlink
```

or add the handler statement to the sub (must have the WithEvents declaration on the variable for this one to work):

```
Private WithEvents Worksheet As {WorkSheet}
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) Handles Worksheet.FollowHyperlink
```